# mysql select query in java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to connecting java with a mysql database. What's wrong with my query here:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM q_table, choices, answers  WHERE q_table.QID='" + number_input + "' AND choices.CID='" + number_input + "' AND answers.AID='" + number_input + "'");
```

Comment: What *goes* wrong? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your statement `" ... q_table.QID='" + number_input + "' AND ...`  the variable `number_input` is enclosed in a single quote ('). This is used for [string lieterals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). If you remove the single quote it should work:

```
 String prest= "SELECT * FROM q_table, choices, answers  WHERE questions.QID=? AND choices.CID=? AND answers.AID=?";

 prest.setInt(1,1980);
 prest.setInt(2,2004);
 .
 .
 ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()){
     String mov_name = rs.getString(1);
     int mov_year = rs.getInt(2);
     count++;
     System.out.println(mov_name + "\t" + "- " + mov_year);
 }
 System.out.println("Number of records: " + count);
 prest.close();
 con.close();
```

Comment: There is an error in your sql. "From q_table ... WHERE questions.QID ..."

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first problem is that you're opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack by including values directly in your SQL. Use a parameterized query instead.

Now we can't really tell what's wrong beyond that, although the fact that you're quoting a *number* seems suspicious, as does the fact that you're using the same value for a question ID, a choice ID and an answer ID. That seems unlikely to be appropriate.

If you could give us more information about what's happening vs what you expected to happen, that would really help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use prepared statements, you can't set the values there.

You have to first prepare the statement using question marks and then set the parameters later.

Here is an example:

```
public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
    PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;

    String updateString = "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
                          "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

    String updateStatement = "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
                             "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? where COF_NAME = ?";

    try {
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
      updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

      for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
        updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateSales.executeUpdate();

        updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateTotal.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
      }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
      JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
      if (con != null) {
        try {
          System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
          con.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException excep) {
          JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
        }
      }
    } finally {
      updateSales.close();
      updateTotal.close();
      con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: No, you *can* include literals in a prepared statement. You just shouldn't, if they're user-provided. Quite often a prepared statement may have a hardcoded literal in.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM **q_table**, choices, answers  WHERE **q_table**.QID='" + number_input + "' AND choices.CID='" + number_input + "' AND answers.AID='" + number_input + "'"

or

SELECT * FROM **questions**, choices, answers  WHERE **questions**.QID='" + number_input + "' AND choices.CID='" + number_input + "' AND answers.AID='" + number_input + "'"

Answer (score 1):

That is not a proper prepareStatement. It's a concatenated query that will only lead you to sql injection horrors. Look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)